# Oracle database compatibility

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Our production Oracle Database version is 10g.
I am trying to install either 11g or 12c on my local machine primarily to access sqlldr.
I am wondering if there are any compatible issues.

Comment: Compatibility issues between what and what?  `SQL*Loader` is a client utility.  Are you trying to install an Oracle client on your local machine or an Oracle database?

Comment: @JustinCave I am trying to install an Oracle client(11g or 12c) on my local machine. Since the server database is 10g and I will be installing a different version of database client on my machine, I wonder if there will be any compatible issues when using tools like sqlldr or accessing the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metalink has the definitive [client/ server compatibility matrix](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=322407164919742&id=207303.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=1bcypv3353_4).  It will depend on the full version of the target database.  Assuming "10g" means 10.2.0.2 or later, you should be fine with a 12.1 client.  If the database is running something earlier than that, you'd generally need an earlier version of the client to be safe.

Comment: It turns out to be 10.2.0.1.0. In this case, I have to go with 11g r2?

Comment: @JohnAl - 11.2 would have the same restrictions.  Either would probably work if all you're using is `SQL*Loader`.  But it would be worth looking through the support matrix and the various footnotes to see if something that you depend on would have issues.